# Non-existence of closed orbits via construction of Liapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

Show that the system

$$\begin{aligned} x^{'} &= y-x^{3}\\ y^{'} &= -x-y^{3}\end{aligned}$$

has no closed orbits by constructing a Liapunov function $$V = ax^{2}+by^{2}$$ with suitable $a$ and $b$.

---

All I really know is that this is an offshoot on the idea of a gradient field and that i want to show that one side = $0$ and the other side clearly isn't $0$ to derive a contradiction but i am defiantly not well verse'd in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(x,y)\not=0$, $V>0$ follows from the stated form of $V$, provided $a,b>0$. But you also need $\dot{V}<0$.

To this end, compute
\begin{align}
\dot{V}&={\partial V\over \partial x}\cdot {dx\over dt}+{\partial V\over \partial y}\cdot{dy\over dt}\\
&=2ax(y-x^3)+2by(-x-y^3)\\
&=2(a-b)xy-2ax^4-2by^4.
\end{align}
Since you only need to find *some* Lyapunov function, make life easy for yourself and choose $a=b$ with $a>0$. Then, for $(x,y)\not=0$,
$$
\dot{V}=-2a(x^4+y^4)<0,
$$
as desired.

Comment: The condition that $V\gt0$ is not needed, is it?

Comment: @Did: Yes; http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LyapunovFunction.html

Comment: Sorry but maths is not theology, yet. If the condition $V\gt0$ is needed, where and why?

Comment: @Did: The link, although not theology, already answered that. Just read it.

Comment: (Amazing comment.) I did read the link and sorry but no, it does not answer that. The condition is mentioned but neither explained nor even, as far as I can see, used.

Comment: *Where?:* Try the 17th and 18th words of the very first sentence in the linked page. *Why?:* If you make it to the third sentence, the rest of the mystery is solved.

Comment: For the record, the third sentence is: *The existence of a Lyapunov function for which V^*(y)<=0 on some region D containing the origin, guarantees the stability of the zero solution of y^'=f(y), while the existence of a Lyapunov function for which V^*(y) is negative definite on some region D containing the origin guarantees the asymptotical stability of the zero solution of y^'=f(y).* Is this supposed to contain a **motivation** for the condition that $V\gt0$? It does not appear so. Balance sheet: level of nastiness = high, level of understanding = low.

Comment: im confused the assumption a=b ^ a>0 force V>0 for all x and y in the reals or no?

Answer (score 1):

As i am unable to comment;

The intuition comes from physics, we think of a Lyapunov function as an energy function that looks like a potential well with a minimum at the origin.

If we can show this energy function is strictly decreasing with time (on some domain), then intuitively everything ends up at whatever value minimizes the energy.

Requiring $V(0)=0$ and $V(x)>0$ $\forall x\in D/0$ simply guarantees there is only one minimum 'energy', and that the minimum is at the origin.